# Project Euler number to word problem

Tags: java

I have tried to develop code for project euler 
[Problem 17](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=17)

I have successfully written a java program and the output appears as expected. But however the online judge says it is the wrong answer. Have a look at my code:

```
package projectEuler;

import java.util.*;
public class Problem17 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
static String []units={"","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"};

static String []special={"Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen",
                    "Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};

static String []tens={"","","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy",
                "Eighty","Ninety"};

static String hundredValue="Hundred and";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{    
 long totalLength=0;
 for(int currentNumber=1;currentNumber<=1000;currentNumber++)
 {
     String currentWord=getWords(currentNumber);
    // System.out.println(currentNumber+"->"+currentWord.replaceAll(" ",""));
     totalLength+=currentWord.replaceAll(" ","").length();

 }
 System.out.print("The total length of all the word is :"+totalLength);
 /*Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter a number :");
 int num = input.nextInt();
 System.out.print(getWords(num));*/
}

public static String getWords(int num) 
{      
    //Find the equivalent word and return it

    String wordValue="";

    switch(String.valueOf(num).length())
    { 
     case 1:
       wordValue=operateOn_1(num);   
     break;

     case 2:
      wordValue= operateOn_2(num);
     break;

     case 3:
      wordValue= operateOn_3(num);
     break;

     default:
      wordValue="One Thousand";  
    }
    return wordValue;
}

public static String operateOn_3(int num) 
{

  String result="";
  result= Problem17.units[num/100]+" "+
          Problem17.hundredValue+" "+
         operateOn_2(Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(num).substring(1))));
  return result;
}

public static String operateOn_2(int num) 
{
    String result="";
   if(String.valueOf(num).charAt(0)=='1')
   {
     result=Problem17.special[num%10];
   }
   else
   {           
       result=Problem17.tens[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((String.valueOf(num)).charAt(0)))];
       result+=" "+operateOn_1(num%10);
   }
    return result;
}

public static String operateOn_1(int num) 
{

    return (Problem17.units[num]);
}

}
```

The total length which the program found out as `21592` but it is wrong according to project euler. If any could have a look at my code and help me please...

Comment: -1 If the online judge says it's wrong then it's wrong, and your task is to find your mistake. Asking on Stackoverflow is cheating. Yes, its's hard, but if you do it yourself you will also be more satisfied when you finally get it right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with the word 'and'

```
static String hundredValue="Hundred and";
```

Which should not occur for numbers such as 300 (Three hundred and)

Comment: @Christopher, Thank you very much for the quick response. Excellent help :)

Comment: @Peter done and done (didn't want to flag or downvote, so I left a comment). To Christopher +1 BTW.

Comment: @Christopher, Thanks a lot.. The one you have mentioned is one bug and also another one is if I enter 204 it returns two hundred and forty four. Fixed it.. The project euler judge accepted the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `"Hundred and"`-problem described by Christopher, there is another issue:

You pass an `int` to `operateOn_2`, which you then convert to a string. This way, you miss the leading zero when converting a number like `101`, which is converted to `One Hundred and Eleven`